# How to process a queue with dropping elements in Angular & rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs, queue

A somewhat difficult problem to explain: In my code, a function is called very often. The return value is an observable. However, the called function takes some time to complete.

The `send()` is the function that is called very often. The `process` function takes some time.

```
send(value) {
    process(value).subscribe( result => {
        ...do something
    })
}
```

What I want to achieve is that `process` is only called as long as `process` is not currently running. However, no the last call should be lost and the last call to `send()` must be executed.

In principle, I would like to have a kind of queue where only the last element is processed. But the question now is: how do I best achieve this.

So far I've tried the following:

```
private isProcessing:boolean;
send(value:any) {
    if (!this.isProcessing) {
        this.isProcessing = true

        process(value).subscribe(result => {
            this.isProcessing = false
            ...do something
       })
    }
}
```

However, under certain circumstances, I lose the last call here. Doe anyone has a smart idea?

Answer (score 1):

Sure! Rxjs operators to the rescue!
I suggest you to create a new Subject and emit to it in the `send` function. Then you should pipe the output from this Subject and map your first observable (a subject is basically an observable) to your observable returned from your `process` function.

In your case is makes sense to either map this first observable to the second one using `exhaustMap` operator or `switchMap` operator. But there is a problem with both of them.

```
private send$ = new Subject<ValueType>();
public send(value) {
  this.send$.emit(value);
}

//either exhaustMap: will not trigger process(value) until last observable from process(value) has completed
private processResult$ = send$.pipe(exhaustMap( value => process(value) ));

//or switchMap: will cancel subscription to last observable coming from process(value) and switch to next one
private processResult$ = send$.pipe(switchMap( value => process(value) ));
```

**Now to the downsights of both solutions:**

**exhaustMap** will ensure that `process` only gets called after last 'run' is completed. Nevertheless it's possible that the last data point is lost. Here the problem is: How do we know which data point is the last one? Will the stream be completed?

**switchMap** will ensure that the last data point is not lost. Nevertheless `process` function will be called for each value emitted. You should ensure that cancel of the subscription leads to no further processing.

Comment: thx for your answer! That helps a bit. As far as I understood the `exhaustMap` if more or less the same as with the `isProcessing` bool flag. While `switchMap` will also process unneeded calls. Do you know a third way that "cleans" all queued entries expect the last one from the stream before calling `process()`?

Comment: Exactly. ExhaustMap works in the same way as your flag. switchMap itself will always subscribe to new newest output from 'process()', but unsubscribe from output which was subscribed to before. I think this is basically what you want, but since I do not know what how 'process()' is working, it's possible that the calculation is done nevertheless, even if no subscription is present anymore.